# Unexpected shape in numpy array of a pillow image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, python-imaging-library

I have built a neural network to detect handwritten digits using the MNIST dataset.

The network takes an input shape of (28,28) as the training MNIST images are 28x28 grayscale.

I now want to test my neural network on some of my own handwriting.

The images I have are not 28x28 grayscale images so I am trying to convert them so that my model will accept them to make predictions.

Currently I have the following:

```
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
newImg = img.resize((28,28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
toPredict = np.array(new_img)
```

However this is giving my an numpy array of shape `(28, 28, 2)` I don't understand this.

After conversion to grayscale and resizing I should have a 28x28 shaped array (28 pixels height multiplied by 28 pixels width).

I don't understand why the shape is not that.

Can anyone help me get the shape to be 28x28 (and explain why it isn't already) so I can pass this to my neural network?

Thank you!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
`img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')` is 28x28x2 because it is greyscale with an alpha channel.
Instead convert it to just greyscale with:

```
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
```

You can see more information on the modes here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#modes